# How can I specify optional characters for regular expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am new to Asp.Net and I want to validate SSN using regularexpressionvalidator. In the regularexpressionvalidator I gave regularexpression as :

```
ValidationExpression="\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}"
```

My regular expression works fine. It says 3 digits then - then 2 digits then - then 4 digits.

However I also want the regular expression to succeed when the textbox is full empty or the textbox contains just:

_ _ *-* _-_ _ _ _

where _ stands for "space" (not _. I've shown _ just so editor can show it up on SO).

How can I do that with regularexpressionvalidator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This pattern should meet all three use cases:

```
^([ ]{3}-[ ]{2}-[ ]{4}|\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4})$
```

I used literal spaces in a character array above rather than `\s`, because `\s` would have also matched tabs, newlines, and other whitespace characters. Also, it is important to keep the space and digit tests separate, not in the same subpattern, otherwise you'd match junk input like `123-__-6_8_`.

Edited: @Dan correctly noted in his answer that the ^ and $ should surround the entire pattern so we match the entire string, not just find an SSN somewhere within it.

Comment: BTW, you don't *have* to have the square brackets around the spaces, I just find that putting spaces in a character array makes them more visible.

Answer (score 2):

The pipe character, `|`, specifies alternate patterns. The pattern `\s{3}-\s{2}-\s{4}` matches the spaces, your pattern `\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}` matches a SSN, and a blank pattern matches an empty input. Therefore, the pattern `^(\s{3}-\s{2}-\s{4}|\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}|)$` should match any of those three.

Comment: Space and `\s` is not the same thing (the latter matches also TAB)

Answer (score 1):

I just googled 'SSN regex':

http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=535&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

`^(?!000)([0-6]\d{2}|7([0-6]\d|7[012]))([ -]?)(?!00)\d\d\3(?!0000)\d{4}$`

Does that help?

Edit: Just seen that you want spaces to work too.  Maybe you could modify the above to do so, by including 'spaces' in the character ranges?

Answer (score 1):

Just test for your two special values before-hand.  Like (pseudo-code):

```
if ((input == "") || (input = "  - -    ")) {
  // valid but "empty"
} else if (input matches your regex) {
  // valid, non-empty input
}
```

If you can't do that, just use the `|` alternative in your RE:

```
ValidationExpression="^(\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}|   -  -    |)$"
```

The anchors are important (unless your framework adds them implicitly), otherwise the empty match won't work, and you would match "garbage" before or after (or both) your desired format. (Check the spaces in the second block, don't just copy/paste it :-) )

Comment: I am using regularexpressionvalidator in asp.net. It has property named RegularExpression. It's just a property. I don't think I can write this long code in there.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with that. Updated with a single RE.

Answer (score 1):

```
"^((\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4})|(_ _ - _-_ _ _ _))$"
```

Accepted input only:
Digits "3 digits, 2 digits, 4 digits" like: `123-45-6789`
Empty: `_ _ - _-_ _ _ _`

Comment: Unfortunately, this will match `123-__-6789`, not just only-spaces or only-digits, and will also not match an empty string.